# Android/Kotlin onClick from a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am working on an app with a Tab layout where the user interfaces with various functions from different fragments. Getting button `onClick` listeners to work is causing me problems and some confusion. I have a fragment that has some number inputs as `EditText`s and buttons that activate methods (in theory). A simple one I want to implement is a rest button that simply resets the value in the number input to `1`. I thought this override of `onClick()` would have worked in the Fragment's `.kt` file:

```
class RatioFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ratio, container, false)
        val offsetResetButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.offsetResetButton)
        offsetResetButton.setOnClickListener(this)
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                RatioFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
    }


    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.offsetResetButton -> {
                hideKeyboard()
                offsetNum = 1
                offsetDen = 1
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetNum).setText("1")
                view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetDen).setText("1")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

but the app crashes when I click the `offsetResetButton` button. The `var`s `offsetNum` and `offsetDen` are from elsewhere in the project, but it seems that trying to access my two text edits and setting new text causes issues. In particular I get the error

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference`

Wonder what's wrong here or if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting tripped up by variable shadowing. Normally, in a `Fragment` with Kotlin, `view` would refer to whatever View you returned from `onCreateView()`, which likely includes the `EditText`s you're looking for. However, your implementation of `onClick()` names its parameter `view`, so `view.findViewById()` will only scan the hierarchy of the view that was clicked.

> ```
> override fun onClick(view: View?) {
>     // ...
>     // these only search within the parameter view, i.e. a Button
>     view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetNum).setText("1")
>     view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetDen).setText("1")
> }
> ```

Change your `onClick()` signature to use a different parameter name:

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    // ...
    // these now search the entire fragment hierarchy
    view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetNum).setText("1")
    view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.offsetDen).setText("1")
}
```

---

Unrelated, but I recommend *not* implementing `View.OnClickListener` in your fragments/activities. Rather, just use a lambda when you set the click listener:

```
val offsetResetButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.offsetResetButton)
offsetResetButton.setOnClickListener { onOffsetResetClick() }
```

```
private fun onOffsetResetClick() {
    // your code here
}
```

When you do it this way, you don't have to worry about `when(view.id)` or anything like that, because you know the method can only be called by clicks on one particular button.

Comment: Interesting...I find the lambda solution much more elegant, but I can*t seem to implement it. I get a member error, Android Studio seems to force requiring an `override fun onClick()` method. @Shay Kin's solution works -- though I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: You have to remove `, View.OnClickListener` from your fragment's declaration